# MVVM pattern, ViewModel Collection

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, observablecollection

I've recently began trying to get the hang of MVVM which doesn't seem to be working yet.

I have my  Models, Views and ViewModels. I have one baseviewmodel that uses the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

I want to make a collection of my `ViewModels` so I can use my data in all my views. But I can't seem to get this going on.

Anyway after reading a ton of different stuff I'm not even sure anymore what's supposed to be what.

My biggest problem which I hope some one can answer for me is where do I dump my collection of `ViewModels`? I need to change one `ViewModel` in a `View` and display it again in another.

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public  BaseViewModel()
    {

    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

That's a `ViewModel` that's being filled in on one view, then needs to be displayed on another view. But I don't know how get this done with the `ObservableCollection<T>` class.

```
public class WorkViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string reference;
    private string address;
    private string scope;
    private string cost;
    private double amount;
    private double gst;
    private double total;

    public string Reference
    {
        get { return reference; }
        set
        {
            if (reference != value)
            { reference = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Reference"); }
        }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set
        {
            if (address != value)
            { address = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Address"); }
        }
    }

    public string Scope
    {
        get { return scope; }
        set
        {
            if (scope != value)
            { scope = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Scope"); }
        }
    }

    public string Cost
    {
        get { return cost; }
        set
        {
            if (cost != value)
            { cost = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Cost"); }
        }
    }

    public double Amount
    {
        get { return amount; }
        set
        {
            if (amount != value)
            {
                amount = value;
                GST = Math.Round(amount * 0.10,2);
                RaisePropertyChanged("Amount");
            }
        }
    }

    public double GST
    {
        get { return gst; }
        set
        {
            if (gst != value)
            {
                gst = value;
                Total = Math.Round(Amount + GST,2);
                RaisePropertyChanged("GST");
            }
        }
    }

    public double Total
    {
        get { return total; }
        set
        {
            if (total != value)
            {
                total = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried this:

```
"Create a BaseViewModel and a Collection ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> _viewModels;

Create a Property ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> ViewModels around _viewModels

Define your View Models like this and add to Collection

MainViewModel : BaseViewModel

Tab1ViewModel : BaseViewModel

Tab2ViewModel : BaseViewModel
```

Now you can use this:

```
Tab1ViewModel vm = (ViewModels.Where(vm => vm is Tab1ViewModel).Count() == 0) ? new  Tab1ViewModel(): (ViewModels.Where(vm => vm is Tab1ViewModel).FirstOrDefault() as Tab1ViewModel;"
```

Seems like I need to make a singleton?

Comment: Please add an example of the problematic code...

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to store a collection of view models anywhere in your design. In my opinion, your view models should be using data from a backing source (most probably your models). In that design, you should be able to instantiate 2 view models of the same type and they both would see the same data because they use the same underlying data. I always have 1 view model instance for each view and it's not shared with any others.

Comment: That's what i'm after but apparently i'm not doing something right

Comment: +1 This article describes having an observable collection in the model represented by two different view-models:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28802/Item-Level-Presentation-Models-for-WPF